# Collision detection using sprites in Pygame

Tags: python, collision-detection, pygame

I'm trying to use collision detection to detect when my mouse hits an image that I've imported.    I get the error "tuple does not have attribute rect"

```
 def main():


    #Call the SDL arg to center the window when it's inited, and then init pygame
    os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"] = "1"
    pygame.init()

    #Set up the pygame window
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,600))


    image_one = pygame.image.load("onefinger.jpg").convert()

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(image_one, (225,400))
    pygame.display.flip()

    while 1:
        mousecoords = pygame.mouse.get_pos() 
        left = (mousecoords[0], mousecoords[1], 10, 10)
        right = image_one.get_bounding_rect()
        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect((left[0]+255, left[1]+400, left[2], left[3]), right):
            print('Hi')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that pygame.sprite.collide_rect() takes two Sprite objects. You are passing it two tuples - neither the cursor nor the image are Sprites and so lack a rect attribute.

You could make a Sprite using image_one, but it will be more tricky to convert the cursor into a Sprite. I think it would be easier to manually test whether the cursor is within the image.

```
#Set up the pygame window
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((200,200))
screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

#Set up image properties (would be better to make an object)
image_one = pygame.image.load("image_one.png").convert()
image_x = 225
image_y = 400
image_width = image_one.get_width()
image_height = image_one.get_height()

# Mouse properties
mouse_width = 10
mouse_height = 10

screen.blit(image_one, (image_x, image_y))
pygame.display.flip()

while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

            # Test for 'collision'
            if image_x - mouse_width < mouse_x < image_x + image_width and image_y - mouse_height < mouse_y < image_y + image_height:
                print 'Hi!'
```

Notice that I test whether the mouse has moved before testing whether it's in the image, to avoid repeating the calculation needlessly.

Comment: Excellent help!  I've found an even easier way to solve it.  When you "blit" an image to a screen, it returns a Rect.  You simply assign a variable equal to that rect, i.e.: FirstL_Rect= screen.blit(image_one, (185,400)), and then do collision detection using the "colliderect" function.  You can transform your mous einto a rect as well by simply doing this:    

mousecoords = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
coordinateRect = Rect(mousecoords[0], mousecoords[1], 10, 10)

Comment: Nice one. I hadn't realised that blitting returns a Rect. That's very useful to know.

Comment: @Parseltongue : you don't need to use the rect returned by `.blit()`: `image_one` is a *Surface*, and as such you can always get its rect with `image_one.get_rect()`. No need to blit at all ;)

Answer (score 2):

Peter suggested, and you also figured it out, that it's easier to work with ***Rects*** instead of *positions* when dealing with collision detection.

I would take that one step further: always work with ***Sprites***!

With Sprites you get access to all those handy collision detection functions in `pygame.sprite`. And if you ever decide to move that image around, it's much easier to update position and animate. It also contains the image surface, all in a single object. Not to mention sprite *Groups*!

Sprites also have a `.rect` attribute, so you can always do low level rect manipulation if you want to with `mysprite.rect`

That said, here's how you can get a Sprite out of your image:

```
image_one = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
image_one.image = pygame.image.load("image_one.png").convert()
image_one.rect = pygame.Rect((image_x, image_y), image_one.image.get_size())
```

Create more sprites for `image_two`, `_three`, etc. Or create a function (or, even better, subclass `Sprite`), receiving position and filename as arguments, so you can create sprites in a *single* line as:

```
image_two = MySprite(filename, x, y)
```

Now you can optionally group them:

```
my_images = pygame.sprite.Group(image_one, image_two, image_three)
```

Drawing is as easy as:

```
my_images.draw(screen)
```

That will blit ***all images at once***, each one in their own positions! Cool, huh?

Let's create a "fake" Sprite for the mouse cursor:

```
mouse = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
mouse.rect = pygame.Rect(pygame.mouse.get_pos(), (1, 1))
```

I've made it a 1x1 sprite so it only collide on mouse hotspot. Notice that it does not have an `.image` attribute (hence "fake" sprite), but pygame does not care since we're not going to draw it anyway.

And now the best part:

```
imagehit = pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(mouse, my_images)
print imagehit
```

In a single line you tested collision against **all images**, and not only you know *if* the mouse collided with any, but also ***which one*** it did!

It really pays off to use Sprites ;)

Answer (score -1):

This isn't related to pygame or python, but may help.

Lazy Foo has a number of great tutorials for SDL, but they are in C++. They are extremely well commented though.  The link to them is here: http://www.lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/index.php